# Add rows to data frame if there is two or more strings in specific column

Tags: r

This is how my data looks like:

```
dd <- data.frame(
  TestGroups = c(
    "P61294;Q0PD53", "O55143", "P16330;Q3TYV5", "P61979;Q3TUA1;Q5FWJ5",
    "P68037;Q561N4", "H3BL37;O08784;Q05BH6;Q7TPZ2", "A0A0R4IZX5;P55066",
    "P27601;Q3UE40", "P11930", "Q9QXS6", "Q9D0K2"
  ),
  Ids = c(
    "P61294;Q0PD53", "O55143", "P16330;Q3TYV5", "P61979;Q3TUA1;Q5FWJ5",
    "P68037;Q561N4", "H3BL37;O08784;Q05BH6;Q7TPZ2", "A0A0R4IZX5;P55066",
    "P27601;Q3UE40", "P11930", "Q9QXS6", "Q9D0K2"
  ),
  Test.Name = c(
    "RAB6B_ART;Q0PD53_ART", "AT2A2_ART", "CN37_ART;Q3TYV5_ART",
    "HNRPK_ART;Q3TUA1_ART;Q5FWJ5_ART", "UB2L3_ART;Q561N4_ART", "H3BL37_ART;TCOF_ART;Q05BH6_ART;Q7TPZ2_ART",
    "A0A0R4IZX5_ART;NCAN_ART", "GNA13_ART;Q3UE40_ART", "NUD19_ART",
    "DREB_ART", "SCOT1_ART"
  ),
  TestDescription = c(
    "Mark", "Barry", "Dirk", "Greg", "Tom", "Tom", "Jerry", "Orfa",
    "Morso", "Orx", "Tesra"
  ),
  Factors = c(
    "Rab6b", "Atp2a2", "Cnp", "Hnrnpk", "Ube2l3", "Tcof1", "Ncan",
    "Gna13", "Nudt19", "Dbn1", "Oxct1"
  ),
  Removed_part = c(
    "TDLADKR", "DACLNAR", "AAARK", "HESGASIK", "NAEEFTK", "TGPAATQAK",
    "VQTASGQR", "TDLLEEK", "DTTTFLEK", "TDAAVEMK", "SGKPGGDVR"
  ),
  row.names = c(62L, 72L, 80L, 96L, 116L, 128L, 139L, 154L, 163L, 172L, 189L)
)
```

I would like to separate strings in column `TestGroups` by adding an additional row. By example lets take first row:

```
 P61294;Q0PD53               P61294;Q0PD53                      RAB6B_ART;Q0PD53_ART            Mark   Rab6b      TDLADKR
```

and that's how my desired output should look like:

```
 P61294               P61294;Q0PD53                      RAB6B_ART;Q0PD53_ART            Mark   Rab6b      TDLADKR
 Q0PD53               P61294;Q0PD53                      RAB6B_ART;Q0PD53_ART            Mark   Rab6b      TDLADKR
```

As you see only strings from first column were taken and separated and put in different rows, rest of the columns was just copied/duplicated.
It may also happen that there will be more than 2 strings in `TestGroups` column. Please also notice that I would like to remove separation mark ';' and just keep pure names.

Answer (score 0):

We could use `separate_longer_delim()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

dd %>% 
  separate_longer_delim(TestGroups, delim = ";") # now recommended
 # separate_rows(TestGroups, sep = ";")
```

```
# A tibble: 21 × 6
   TestGroups Ids                  Test.Name                       TestDescription Factors Removed_part
   <chr>      <chr>                <chr>                           <chr>           <chr>   <chr>       
 1 P61294     P61294;Q0PD53        RAB6B_ART;Q0PD53_ART            Mark            Rab6b   TDLADKR     
 2 Q0PD53     P61294;Q0PD53        RAB6B_ART;Q0PD53_ART            Mark            Rab6b   TDLADKR     
 3 O55143     O55143               AT2A2_ART                       Barry           Atp2a2  DACLNAR     
 4 P16330     P16330;Q3TYV5        CN37_ART;Q3TYV5_ART             Dirk            Cnp     AAARK       
 5 Q3TYV5     P16330;Q3TYV5        CN37_ART;Q3TYV5_ART             Dirk            Cnp     AAARK       
 6 P61979     P61979;Q3TUA1;Q5FWJ5 HNRPK_ART;Q3TUA1_ART;Q5FWJ5_ART Greg            Hnrnpk  HESGASIK    
 7 Q3TUA1     P61979;Q3TUA1;Q5FWJ5 HNRPK_ART;Q3TUA1_ART;Q5FWJ5_ART Greg            Hnrnpk  HESGASIK    
 8 Q5FWJ5     P61979;Q3TUA1;Q5FWJ5 HNRPK_ART;Q3TUA1_ART;Q5FWJ5_ART Greg            Hnrnpk  HESGASIK    
 9 P68037     P68037;Q561N4        UB2L3_ART;Q561N4_ART            Tom             Ube2l3  NAEEFTK     
10 Q561N4     P68037;Q561N4        UB2L3_ART;Q561N4_ART            Tom             Ube2l3  NAEEFTK     
# … with 11 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```